# Filtering Two lists with Java8

Tags: java, spring

I have two ArrayList which contains a list of user-defined classes with a large volume of data. One of the lists contains the elements of another list.

I want to filter out the data from list1 which is already present in list2 in a new list3.

I can do this with the help of looping but as the volume of data is very large, I don't want to use looping.

```
Example:
List<Presentation> presentedDepartmentList               //list 1 
List<PresentationDetails> excludingDepartmentList        //list 2

Both Presentation and PresentationDetails have a common field as 
"departmentNumber". I want to filter out the entries in the 
"excludingDepartmentList" from the "presentedDepartmentList".
```

As I am unfamiliar with Java8, I am having difficulty in the task.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you filter one collection of size N against a list of size M, the time required will be O(N*M). If M is large, first convert it to a hash set, then your time will be O(N + M).

```
Set<String> exclusions = excludingDepartmentList.stream()
    .map(PresentationDetails::getDepartmentNumber)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
List<Presentation> filtered = presentedDepartmentList.stream()
    .filter(p -> !exclusions.contains(p.getDepartmentNumber()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Damn this is a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Much Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
List<Presentation> filteredList = presentedDepartmentList.stream().filter(this::shouldBeIncluded).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

....

```
public boolean shouldBeIncluded(Presentation presentation) {
    !(excludingDepartmentList.stream().filter(a -> presentation.departmentNumber().equals(a.departmentNumber())).findAny().isPresent());
}
```

Comment: This also worked. I marked the other one correct as it was the better approach. Thanks for the help and time.

Comment: Haha sure thing thanks. You can always upvote answers you find helpful.